# Asp.net-Mvc Display self join in dropdownlistFor control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, html.dropdownlistfor

I am using LINQ Self Join Query to display data on the dropdownlistFor  view .my sql table contains some employees details:

```
   EmpID  Name  ManagerID   Designation   Phone   Address
     1    Mike    3          Developer    123456   Texas
     2    David   3           RM          123456   Delhi
     3    Roger   NULL        GM          123456   Dallas
     4    Marry   2          Developer    123456   NY
     5    Joseph  2          Developer    123456   Singapore
```

I am trying to create OR Add new employee to employee table, i display `ManagerID` in dropdownlist html control and name of `manager` also with self 
 join this self join select only name of the `manager` the probelm is when i try to insert new employee i can not get `manager-id` to insert it to employee table .

this is my query :

```
 var empmngr = from m in db.Employes
                      join e1 in db.Employes on m.ManagerID   equals e1.EmpID
                      select
                       e1.Name;



        ViewData["EmployeeManager"] = new SelectList(empmngr.ToList());
```

this is the view :

```
   <div class="editor-label">
        EmployeeManager
    </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ManagerID   , 
        ViewData["EmployeeManager"] as SelectList)            
    </div>
```

this is when i create new employe:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(EmployesContact emp) // Record Insert  
    {
        var objEmployee = new Employe
        {
            Name = emp.Name,             
            ManagerID   = emp.ManagerID   ,  this is null when i try to insert new employee             

        };
     }
```

i think this problem when i am trying to select managerID with self join to display it on the dropdownlistFot control

any advice i am new stuff 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

this answer do self join and display managerid and name of manger in the `html.dropdownlistfor` control  I get the right answer for my question :

```
       var empmngr = from m in db.Employes
                      join e1 in db.Employes on m.ManagerID   equals e1.EmpID
                      select new {
                          e1.Name ,
                          m.ManagerID   
                     };

        ViewData["EmployeeManager"] = new SelectList(empmngr.ToList(), "ManagerID   ", "Name");
```